# ADFS authenticated on IE for Web App1 prompts login page for WebApp2 on Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, wif, adfs2.0

My application is configured for SSO and there is other web app which is also configured for single sign on on the ADFS server with same domain and active directory.

I try to access webapp1 on IE and then try to open web app1 in chrome.

can anyone please tell whether it will work on this scenario 
or Am I missing any settings?

Please let me know if any setting or configuration change is required.

When I try to access both app on same browser it works. Logging in to first app make me authenticated on second app. I think that is because of cookies.

Can anyone please clear this concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sso requires cookies in the browser.  Different browser or browser instances don't share cookies.  This doesn't work by design.

Comment: Thanks Willy, So is that cookie will give access to any application (which uses "FedAuth") or just those application which are trusted by STS? Will I get access to those application which are not trusted by my STS but uses "FedAuth" cookie?

Comment: Your relying party will (typically) drop a multipart cookie in its own domain.  This contains the session cookie for that relying party.  Each relying party has such a set of cookies.  They don't serve for SSO, they just serve fo rthe "session" of the relyin gparty.  In addition to that, the STS will drop a cookie in the domain of the adfs.  That one is the one that provides sso.  You typically cannot share the cookies of one relying party with another one.  Each relying party typically has to be known by the STS in order to get sso.

Comment: Thanks again Willy. It helped to clear my concept about cookie. Can you please answer my this question regarding session sliding? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007507/adfs-freshness-and-session-sliding